# How to overlap block elements when using jQuery display on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Maybe I am going about this wrong, but I have a form with part of it's content temp removed ...

```
.form_jquery {display: none;}
```

and I am displaying the content when the parent div and title are hovered...

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        $(".deliver").hover(
            function () {
            $(".form_jquery").css({'display':'block'});
            },
                function () {
                    $(".form_jquery").css({'display':'none'});
                }
         )
    });
```

The problem is, I have a "main content" area under this form title/toggle and when we...

```
css({'display':'block'})
```

The lower block element is pushed down. I have tried a few display element options on the lower block with adverse reactions. My last resort will be to set my form as "fixed", but I did want it to simulate a menu title and scroll with that group.

http://www.testinr.com/

Comment: you might need to show us the page or a JSfiddle to illustrate the problem

Comment: @greener http://www.testinr.com/

Comment: what exactly is being pushed down? The 'HOME' box is staying in place, and the form is appearing and disappearing as one could expect?

Comment: @greener Interesting, I have been developing in Firefox. It works as you say in Chrome, but Firefox messes up.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following items to your css

```
.deliverOnHover
{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 99;
    display: block;
}
body{
    position: absolute;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

And Jquery will be something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $(".deliver").hover(function(){
         $(".form_jquery").toggleClass('deliverOnHover');
    });
});
```

and add `position:absolute` to the css of the div below.

Comment: Does not work. I still get "Home" dropping down in firefox, not to mention this code only toggles the parent node of my form, leaving content (children) not effected by function. I will play with it a bit though.